# Load Function not updating Global Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, global-variables, ejs

I'm creating a node application and having trouble updating a global variable.

Here is my code (ejs file):

```
 <% include ../partials/header %>

    <div class="page container">
        <div id="campgroundsRow" class="row">
        </div> <!-- row end -->
        <button id="loadMore">Load More</button>
    </div> <!-- Container End -->
    <% include ../partials/footer %>

    <script>
        var numGroundsToLoad = 1;
        var numGroundsLoaded = 0;

        loadCampgrounds(numGroundsLoaded, numGroundsToLoad);

        function loadCampgrounds(numGroundsLoaded, numGroundsToLoad) {
              var grounds = <%-JSON.stringify(campgrounds) %>
              for(var i=numGroundsLoaded + 1; i<numGroundsLoaded + numGroundsToLoad; i++) {
                   //code to add grounds[i] to campgroundsRow div
              }
              numGroundsLoaded += numGroundsToLoad;
        }

        $("#loadMore").on("click", function() {
              loadCampgrounds(numGroundsLoaded, numGroundsToLoad);   
        });
    </script>
```

The problem I'm having is the `loadCampgrounds` function is not actually updating `numGroundsLoaded`. So when I click the load more button (`#loadMore`), it thinks that I am adding `ground[0].`

What I want is that each time I click load more, the next ground is added. I.e, `ground[0]` gets added by default. Then on load more, `ground[1]`. Then on load more, `ground[2]` and so on (assume there are unlimited grounds for now).

As you can see, the problem is related to both scope and when stuff is being loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you update the local variable. In this case, to update global variable you need to access it through `window.numGroundsLoaded`.

Comment: Thats perfect. It worked. Can you explain why though? (I'm accepting your answer, but it says wait 10 min)

Comment: Because all changes you apply to the local variable are not applying to the original variable. Even if you pass an object, you can modify its properties but not a reference to this object. It is explaining in this doc (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions).